# Is there any performance reduction for simple if?

Tags: c++, performance

For example, I have a class

```
class Point
{
public:
    float operator[](int i) const
    {
       if (i == 0) return m_x; // simple ifs, performance reduction??
       if (i == 1) return m_y;
       return m_z;
    }

private:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
    float m_z;
};
```

Is there any performance reduction compare to access an element of `std::array<float, 3>`? If so, how can I remove it. I want to use fields x, y, z other than an array.

Comment: I think you mean `float operator[](int i)`

Comment: Indeed, performance reduction compared to what? Ifs are not free. If the argument to the `if` is a constant expression then it may be "free" at runtime. But that is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my question.

Comment: You could answer your own question by compiling with optimizations turned on and look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the performance of what you've written is impacting your actual code? (Does a profiler indicate that this code is a bottleneck?) If not, this is one of those obvious cases of premature optimization.

Comment: @TianXiao Please [see this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O3',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKGgM0yQAV1xsyBvMgBxgCMoQIAuMkiFIAZlHQFsSdGwS5J6XAG0AugApGSEAEokEdGByDhrYWZAikGpAF4bSAAy782GLjBIiAfQAeAbiQAekCkTBAiNihkC0wAGiRZXBFFIgJIZHw4GAhsDDAAfnzjMy1LazskAEZnBFd3Ty8ATz9isxc3D28ALxazAF8ydlwQADdJBAEzMQkpb39W6ckG5oXxJe6WvpayTVTwNW0WY3pNNl7RNakfWwSlBxVznDg%2BPn0YKRQUJHm%2BoAAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)  -- Aren't optimizing compilers amazing things?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't understand assembly. How does it say? No performance reduction?

Comment: You should write whatever most clearly reflects the intention of the code and makes it easiest to understand and maintain. Performance should not be considered for cases like this.

Comment: Correctly measuring this might actually be a fun exercise. You may wanna watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk).

Comment: @TianXiao Here is the [unoptimized code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKGgM0yQAV1xsyBvMgBxgCMoQIAuMkiFIAZlHQFsSdGwS5J6XAG0AugApGSEAEokEdGByDhrYWZAikGpAF4bSAAy782GLjBIiAfQAeAbiQAekCkTBAiNihkC0wAGiRZXBFFIgJIZHw4GAhsDDAAfnzjMy1LazskAEZnBFd3Ty8ATz9isxc3D28ALxazAF8ydlwQADdJBAEzMQkpb39W6ckG5oXxJe6WvpayTVTwNW0WY3pNNl7RNakfWwSlBxVznDg%2BPn0YKRQUJHm%2BoAAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Comment: @TianXiao The point being that fiddling with an `if` statement here or there like in your example rarely if ever results in measurably faster or slower code.  By the time the compiler's optimizer handles the code, that `if` statement becomes a moot point.

Comment: @paul I think that's the real answer here. I would have written it up myself, along with a brief explanation of what the assembly means (essentially, look ma no branches), but since you posted the comment, I thought you should get first dibs. It is the "teach a man how to fish" answer, which I am quite fond of anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any performance reduction?

I assume you mean, "compared to doing an array lookup".

If so, the answer is (potentially) yes -- any branching operation can potentially cause a pipeline stall (if the CPU mispredicts which branch will be taken), which could make things slower.  CPU branch prediction is pretty good these days, so it might not be an issue in real life--it would depend a lot on the usage patterns of the program that is calling this code.

> If so, how can I remove it. I want to use fields x, y, z other than
>   an array.

You can remove the ifs by using a three-item array instead of three separate items.

If you don't like accessing the items as an array, you can always add accessor methods to make the array look like separate items again:

```
class Point 
{
public:
   [...]

   float & m_x() {return m_array[0];}
   float & m_y() {return m_array[1];}
   float & m_z() {return m_array[2];}

private:
   float m_array[3];
};

[...]

myPoint.m_x() = 5;
myPoint.m_y() = myPoint.m_x() + myPoint.m_z();
[etc]
```

Comment: Does accessing `m_array[i]` take more CPU time than accessing `m_x`?

Comment: Not on a modern CPU, no.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I think technically it might. Since when you use `m_x` the pointer arithmetic can be done at compile-time, and with `m_array[i]`, it cannot. But it probably won't be noticeable.

Comment: @ChrisBeck But above `i` is a `constexpr` like `1`, so the arithmetic can be done statically.

Comment: @chi: Is that clear? It might or might not be I think

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your data as separate members, you could store it in an array. Then do array indexing in the getter functions for the members.

```
class Point
{
public:
    float operator[](int i)
    {
       return coords[i]
    }
    float getX() {
        return coords[0];
    }
    float getY() {
        return coords[1];
    }
    float getZ() {
        return coords[2];
    }
    float setX(float val) {
        return coords[0] = val;
    }
    float setY(float val) {
        return coords[1] = val;
    }
    float setZ(float val) {
        return coords[2] = val;
    }

private:
    float coords[3];
};
```

Comment: Can't you just use a plain reference like `float &m_x;` and alias it to `coords[0]`?

Comment: I don't like the idea of providing direct access to the internal representation like that. What if you decide to change the way it's stored?

Comment: @melpomene Notice that the member variables were declared private in the original code, so the intent is to hide the representation.

Comment: @melpomene One drawback to adding a reference object is that it more than doubles the size of your Point objects (which might be undesirable if there are going to be a lot of them).  Another drawback is that it might make accesses to the objects more expensive (since they would likely require resolving a layer of indirection).  Using methods instead avoids those issues.

Answer (score -3):

As others have noted, your syntax isn't correct.  But to answer your question, you could do so in the following way:

```
float operator[](int i) {
    return *(&m_x + i);
}
```

Address of operator, add the index, and dereference resultant pointer.

This would perform better than two if statements.  Of course, you would have to be careful to only provide valid values of i (from 0 to 2).

This also assumes your members are properly aligned and aren't using any specific compiler features.  You of course need to be aware of how your memory is stored, but this is definitely the most optimal as it's common understanding that arithmetic operations perform faster than conditions due to how processors are designed.

Comment: I think it would be risky to do that, since that math assumes that the three member variables are laid out in a particular order, with no padding between them.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks. Now specified.

Comment: @MikeWeir You're missing the point. Also [citation needed] for "this would perform better".

Comment: @melpomene Could you elaborate on the point missed? Just trying to help here.

Comment: @MikeWeir You're assuming that m_y will be located at a memory location exactly one floating-point-value-size after m_x, and that m_z will be located at a memory location exactly one floating-point-value-size after m_y.  But the C++ standard does not guarantee that, and while it's likely that they are laid out that way in most cases, it's also quite likely that you are invoking undefined behavior by calculating the addresses that way, and in particular doing that might break some of the compiler's optimizations, since the optimizer might not realize what you are doing "behind its back"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I understand that there is theoretical concerns with this approach.  However, every C++ compiler I have ever used, an approach like this is in fact expected often times.  In what situation would you have a compiler that would not have them aligned as such?  The only way to do so is to force a custom member padding with the compiler, something that I'm not suggesting here.  From a practical standpoint, this solution is most optimal, and it's common understanding that arithmetic is faster than conditions.

Comment: @MikeWeir imagine that the compiler has cached the value of m_y in a register.  Now you write a different value to m_y using your technique, but the code generated by the optimizer doesn't realize what you've done, because it's not in the C++ spec.  So when the generated code later saves the in-register value back to m_y, it overwrites the value you manually placed there, and now you're left trying to figure out why your program gives the wrong result.   (moral of the story:  modern C++ optimizers are very ambitious, so you really want to stick to the C++ spec or they will mess with you)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think you're severely mistaken if you believe that is an outcome. Under no circumstance would that happen. These are member variables and not local variables.

Comment: @MikeWeir See this link:  https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/VOID+CTR37-CPP.+Do+not+add+or+subtract+an+integer+to+a+pointer+to+a+non-array+object

Comment: He is not *severely mistaken* because if you rely on UB you're off. If you write an implementation for your own compiler where you on your own can guarantee that the code will work you're probably fine. In any other case there is abosultely NO guarantee whatsoever. Your argument is void.It's like saying: '*You won't get caught when stealing socks because I stole a pair of socks in all mayor chain stores I have ever been to without getting caught.*'

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That link doesn't relate to what you said.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Member variables do not get cached by the compiler under any circumstance where you wouldn't be able to alias them in this way. It's extremely vital to have memory in a predictable manner for many optimizations out there. You're basically arguing that memory tricks in C++ should never be used because you might have a compiler that will screw you over. You're being a bit over pedantic arguing this point when in reality, this solution is wildly used in game/physics programming.